# Pandas Raises ValueError When Trying To Use A List For Column Names

Tags: python, file, pandas, error-handling, dataframe

The following code below causes Pandas to raise a ValueError. I'm not sure why as using a normal list works fine.

```
fileFields = [str(input("Please enter the column name for the pedigree field in
                  your request file.\n")),
              str(input("Please enter the column name for the pedigree field
                  in the Tissue Library file.\n")),
              str(input("Please enter the column name for the sourceID field
                  in the Tissue Library file.\n")),
              str(input("Please enter the column name for the pedigree field in 
                  the Gold Standard file.\n")),
              str(input("Please enter the column name for the sourceID field in
                  the Gold Standard file.\n"))]

dfRequests = pd.read_csv(fileInputs[0], skipinitialspace=True,
                         usecols=fileFields[0])
dfTissueLibrary = pd.read_csv(fileInputs[1], skipinitialspace=True,
                              usecols=fileFields[1:2])
dfGoldStandard = pd.read_csv(fileInputs[2], skipinitialspace=True,
                             usecols=fileFields[3:4])
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepathway hidden for security", line 74, in <module>
    usecols=fileFields[0])
  File "filepathway hidden for security\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 529, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "filepathway hidden for security\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 295, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "filepathway hidden for security\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 612, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "filepathway hidden for security\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 747, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "filepathway hidden for security\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1154, in __init__
    col_indices.append(self.names.index(u))
ValueError: 'd' is not in list
```

I feel as if Pandas is taking the string from each index in the fileFields list and turning them into lists of strings. I tried resolving this by making the indexed strings lists after calling them but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `fieldField[0]` returns a string (the first column entered), so `d` is probably the first character of the first column, right? If so, set `usecols=fieldFields`.

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions?

My approach would be to use a small helper function as follows that makes the process simple and safe:

```
def selective_read_csv(purpose, path):
    # read just the header row and get the column names
    columns = list(pd.read_csv(path, nrows=1).columns.values)
    df = None
    while df is None:
        # present user with a selection of actual columns, taking
        # out the guess work
        file_fields = raw_input("[%s] Enter columns as a comma-separated list %s " % (purpose, columns))
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=file_fields.split(','))
        except ValueError as e:
            print "Sorry, %s" % e
            df = None
    return df
df = selective_read_csv('requests file', '/tmp/data.csv')
```

This way users are prompted with columns that are actually in the file and erroneous input is handled nicely:

```
[requests file] Enter columns as a comma-spearated list [u'a', u'b'] aaa
Sorry, 'aaa' is not in list
[requests file] Enter columns as a comma-spearated list [u'a', u'b']
```

Then call this function for each file type, e.g.:

```
dfRequests = selective_read_csv('requests file', fileInputs[0])
dfTissueLibrary = selective_read_csv('tissue library', fileInputs[1])
dfGoldStandard = selective_read_csv('gold standard', fileInputs[2])
```